# How to get SIM roaming status in iOS

Tags: ios

In one of my app I would like to know Sim card roaming status.
Android network info provide is roaming() function for it but I didn't find any way in iOS.
I am looking for the proper solution because I don't want to get reject my app by apple due to any reason.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, Apple does not provide an API that allows you to check this.

I've developed an app for the mobile telephone provide and they even asked Apple whether it would be possible. Apple replayed that they do not offer an API for this. Thus we are nog using some very complex check when the device a on a mobile network, which I can not disclose because it is specific for this provider.